# Set cookie not working with varnish

Tags: varnish, cookie, magento2.4.4

I've created the following observer method that sets a cookie:

```
       if ($this->_cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME)) {
            $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie(
                self::COOKIE_NAME,
                $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
                    ->createCookieMetadata()
                    ->setPath('/')
                    ->setDomain(null)
            );
        }

        $metadata = $this->_cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration(self::COOKIE_DURATION)
            ->setPath('/')
            ->setDomain(null);

        $this->_cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            self::COOKIE_NAME,
            $mediumValue,
            $metadata
        );
```

It observes the event `controller_action_predispatch` to run on all pages.
This code works perfectly when Varnish is disabled, but when I enable varnish, this code no longer sets the new cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard VCL code for Magento actively removes `Set-Cookie` headers from pages otherwise cacheable pages.

Here's some relevant VCL code from [the Varnish Developer portal](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/#optimized-magento-vcl-file) for dealing with responses prior to storing them in the cache:

```
# Only cache HTTP 200 & HTTP 404 responses
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
    set beresp.ttl = 120s;
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    return (deliver);
# Don't cache private responses
} elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
    set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
    return (deliver);
}

# Remove the Set-Cookie header for cacheable content
# Only for HTTP GET & HTTP HEAD requests
if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

As you can see, the standard VCL code will strip off all `Set-Cookie` headers for cacheable content that was triggered by an HTTP `GET` or `HEAD` request.

If the response status code is not `200` or `404`, or when there's a `Cache-Control: private` header set, Varnish will keep the `Set-Cookie` in the response.

The solution is to add the `Cache-Control: private` header to the response that sets the cookie.

Comment: Don't you think removing `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;` is a better solution?

Comment: @AboElnouR you could try that, but I'm afraid there will be responses where Magento sends responses that include an unwanted `Set-Cookie`. Please try and check if your hit rate is still acceptable.

Comment: Can't I create a condition if I have an exact query to pass this statement?

Comment: @AboElnouR let me know what the condition is and what action to execute and I'll update my answer with the updated VCL

Comment: I've set no-cache headers for this request and it works, but I'm not sure if this should be the best practice or allowing the set cookie in the default vcl file.

Comment: @AboElnouR In theory a `Cache-Control: no-cache` should work, but Magento seems to override this behavior in the VCL file and prefer `Cache-Control: private` instead. Maybe your VCL file looks slightly different. In terms of best-practices, setting a cookie changes state, so having a `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` is the way to go. Any variant of that `Cache-Control` header that prevents caching is also good.

Comment: I'm grateful to you as I believe this is the best practice.